# Remove an available option from the "From" for Case Emails?

Tags: email, case, email2case, support

Our Support Manager is set as the default user for our Support Cases.
When he goes to send an email it defaults to 'Managers Name'

Is there any way to remove this option all-together?

Both alternatives still show and he can switch them, but it is very tedious and when he doesn't remember we receive his individual email in the Support Queue.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are talking about **Organization Wide Email Addresses**. A good link on this topic is here: http://training.handsonconnect.org/m/customizing/l/36852-creating-new-organization-wide-email-addresses.

In answer to your question, you can remove it altogether (you can delete an Organization Wide Email Address by selecting 'del') *or* you can remove it as an option for your colleague(s) by making the email address not applicable to their Profile(s).